# How do we use the idiom "come down on"?

Tags: idioms, usage

How do we use the idiom "come down on"?

Looked up a dictionary and found the following:

> come down on (someone or something)
>
> 1. To scold or reprimand one harshly. It was a mistake, so don't come down on him too hard, OK?
> 2. To establish one's opinion or view as being in support of a particular side of an issue. And where do you come down on this issue,
>      sir? I think the jury is going to come down on the side of the
>      plaintiff.
> 3. To actively oppose someone or something or attempt to prevent or abolish something. This issue is unjust, and as your mayor I promise
>      to come down on it.

The issue is that I am wondering if we can say **come down on something on someone** or **come down on someone on something**

> He came down on me on the argument I made against her.

There's no usage rule, so I thought this made sense, but I am not sure. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

While your example:

> He came down on me on the argument I made against her.

would I think be understood, I don't think it is the usual way that idiom would be employed. More likely would be:

> - He came down on me **about** the argument I made against her.
> - He came down on me **over** the argument I made against her.
> - He came down on me **for** the argument I made against her.

There is no particular logic that I know of why "about" or "over" should be used rather than "on" except perhaps that the repeated use of "on" feels confusing or awkward.  I believe that I have heard "about" more often than "over" in such a construction.

"in regard to" could be used instead of "about" but "come down on" is a rather informal usage, and "in regard to" is a bit formal, so there is a bit of a style clash using the two together.

Other words might be used to connect "come down on" with the subject of the scolding or discussion.

I don't recall ever having heard "come down on" used in sense 3 above. But that doesn't mean I deny that some people use it that way.

Comment: I was just about to answer that I thought "for" would be a more normal preposition here: 'He came down on me for the argument I made against her' similar to the usage in 'He came down on me for arguing.' I also have never heard it in sense three.

Comment: @katy Yes "for" seems a reasonable usage here also. I will add it to the answer, and thank you.